# How do I force my Spree app to run in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, spree

I've tried almost everything.

In my nginx.conf I have `rails_env` set to `production` in server and http.

I have in my environment.rb `RAILS_ENV='production'`, as well as `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'`
.

Still it loads in development. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option to try is setting `RACK_ENV=production`. Probably they reworked default initializers.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. This is a daft question, but *where* would you put that `RACK_ENV=production`? In an initializer?

Comment: Just prepend it to the start command. like `RACK_ENV=production bin/spree_startup.sh start`